# How to convert a word document into Json in apache tika

Tags: solr, solrj, apache-tika

I am very new to big data and Tika. I just want to know is there a way to convert a word document(.doc) to JSON format. I heard that a morphline using java needs to coded to do this, but i dont know Java, Is there any solution available to this.

I will be using Tika in Apache SolR.

Comment: why do you want to convert to json, or does the word contain json string?

Comment: @kuhajeyan, I want use Tika inside Solr. Solr accepts only Json or XML formats

Comment: You can index Word Files in Solr. Why would you want to convert it to json?

Comment: See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like following you can extract xml with ToXMLContentHandler and then convert to json

More examples [here](https://tika.apache.org/1.8/examples.html)

```
public String parseBodyToHTML(InputStream stream) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {
    ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(
            new ToXMLContentHandler());

    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
    return handler.toString();
}
```

another option would be write a JsonHandler for yourself [ContentHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html?is-external=true)

Comment: Thanks  a lot. Will try this solution and let you know the feedback.

Comment: thanks for the solution. I just have one more query. I was told that we need to have morphline (to be written in Java) to convert docs to Json. Could you please let me know your opinon on this please?. Sorry i am very new to these technologies hence these basic questions.

Comment: @SijoK, i haven't done a one for myself, that may another question you may ask or update this question. you should be able get help from someone who had done it.